# Как сохранить сложный объект с помощью Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

Есть задача - сохранить сложный объект с помощью `Python`. Я начал гуглить, как это сделать, и нашёл, что для подобных целей часто используется *jsonpickle*. В интернете можно найти множество примеров, как некие объекты, например, классы легко сохранить в файл с помощью данной библиотеки.

Но у меня сложный объект, и с ним `jsonpickle` не справляется. 
Как можно решить задачу? Сохранить сложный объект в файл?

Вот моя попытка справиться с задачей.

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver 
import jsonpickle

# driver - сложный объект, который мы хотим 
driver = webdriver.Firefox() научиться сохранять
# кодируем его, чтобы потом можно было сохранить в файл
obj = jsonpickle.encode(driver)
# раскодируем, чтобы проверить, работает ли этот метод 
obj = jsonpickle.decode(obj) 
# у нас получается зайти в Firefox на указанную страницу правильно
driver.get("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask")
# У нас не получается зайти на указанную страницу с помощью нового объекта,
# то есть стандартный метод сохранения сложного объекта не работает 
obj.get("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask")
```

Как сохранить действительно сложный объект *driver*? В интернете нахожу лишь примеры с сохранением простейших классов. Но на реальной задаче мы видим, что это не работает.

Comment: Безумно сложно представить сценарий использования такого решения? Сохранить веб-драйвер для чего? Такое применимо, если используется модель распределенных вычислений, когда надо шарить объекты между разными процессами, особенно на разных машинах, чтобы их обрабатывать.. Если объект совсем сложный, крайнем случае, можно сохранить аргументы, необходимые для создания какого-нибудь объекта. Но вебдрайвер? Могу ли я просить удовлетворить мое любопытство?